# Linux find and grep for files not match pattern

Tags: linux, search, find, grep, regex

I'm trying to search the entire file system for specific text. This command does that but it gets hung up in certain directories like '/proc':

```
find / -print0|xargs -0 grep whatever
```

What I'd like to do is only send files to grep that don't match '/sys' '/proc' '/tmp' '/lib'.

**Update**:
After the help from Gary below I needed to add a few more excluded directories so I decided to write a python script to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
import time
import re

search = "192.168.30"
searchRoot = "/"
reobj = re.compile(r"^/var|^/dev|^/proc|^/sys|^/bin|^/boot|^/home|^/lost|^/media|^/misc|^/mnt|^/net|^/sbin|^/selinux|\.log")

start = time.time()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchRoot):
    for name in files:
        fullPath = os.path.join(root, name)
        if not reobj.search(fullPath):
            try:
                fileSize = os.path.getsize(fullPath)
                if (fileSize < 51200):
                    try:
                        #print fullPath
                        fileobj = open(fullPath, 'r')
                        text = fileobj.read()
                        fileobj.close()
                        index = text.find(search)
                        if (index > -1):
                            print index, ":", fullPath
                            sys.stdout.flush()
                    except:
                        pass
            except:
                pass

print "Completed search for", search, "in", searchRoot, "in",  time.time() - start, "seconds."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `grep`, which is what you're using if you're running Linux, will do recursive searches by itself, without the need for `find` and `xargs`. It also has an `--exclude-dir` option to "Exclude directories matching the pattern DIR from recursive searches." So you could write your search as

```
grep -R --exclude-dir=/sys --exclude-dir=/proc --exclude-dir=/tmp --exclude-dir=/lib whatever /
```

---

Update following comment:

If your `grep` doesn't support `-R` or `--exclude-dir`, then you might have to resort to `find` and `xargs`, which work fine, but have messy syntax for this task. I seldom get it right the first time.

```
find / -path /sys -prune -o \( -path /proc -prune -o \( -path /tmp -prune -o \( -path /lib -prune \) \) \) -o -print0 | xargs -0 grep whatever
```

Comment: Looks like my version of grep doesn't support that argument. I'm on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6. This is the man page for the version I have: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep .

Comment: Hmm it looks like that filters to include the dirs i'm trying to exclude. If I run this:

Comment: When the preceding `-name` or `-path` term matches, `-prune` tells `find` to stop searching that branch of the file system tree. Read the find(1) man page, the section on the `-prune` option for a better explanation. I tested that command briefly on my Fedora 14 system and it seemed to work properly.

Comment: I needed to add a few more directories to the exclusion list and that syntax is just too hard to read. I wrote a python script to do something similar. Thanks for your help Gary!